# ObjectDisposedException when moving form

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a custom form.

Now I'm trying to implement the feature to drag the form around while holding the titlebar. But it always throws this exception:

> system.ObjectDisposedException

Has anyone an idea what the problem is?

This is my code:

```
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    Form form;
    Button buttonCancel;
    Button buttonOk;
     DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
    {

        form = new Form();
        buttonCancel = new Button();
        buttonOk = new Button();

        Label label = new Label();
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

        Panel titlebar = new Panel();
        Label lbltitle = new Label();
        Panel pnlexit = new Panel();
        Label lblexit = new Label();


        form.Text = title;
        label.Text = promptText;
        textBox.Text = value;

        buttonOk.Text = "OK";
        buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

        label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);
        buttonCancel.Location = new Point(250, 100);
        buttonCancel.Parent = form;
        buttonCancel.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CDDC39");
        buttonCancel.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        buttonCancel.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        buttonCancel.MouseClick += ButtonCancel_MouseClick;

        buttonOk.Location = new Point(170, 100);
        buttonOk.Parent = form;
        buttonOk.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CDDC39");
        buttonOk.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        buttonOk.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;


        form.Height = 150;
        form.Width = 350;
        form.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#455A64");
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        form.AutoSize = false;
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
        form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;


        titlebar.Width = form.Width;
        titlebar.Height = 25;
        titlebar.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#37474F");
        titlebar.Parent = form;
        titlebar.Controls.Add(pnlexit);
        titlebar.MouseDown += Titlebar_MouseDown;

        lblexit.Text = "X";
        lblexit.Font = new Font("Arial", 9.5f, FontStyle.Bold);
        lblexit.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        lblexit.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        lblexit.MouseClick += lblexit_click;

        pnlexit.Height = titlebar.Height - 10;
        pnlexit.Width = 30;
        pnlexit.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CDDC39");
        pnlexit.Location = new Point(titlebar.Width - 33, 0);
        pnlexit.Parent = titlebar;
        pnlexit.Controls.Add(lblexit);

        lbltitle.Parent = titlebar;
        lbltitle.Text = title;
        lbltitle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CDDC39");
        lbltitle.Font = new Font("Arial",  9.5f, FontStyle.Bold);
        lbltitle.Location = new Point(5, 3);

        label.AutoSize = true;
        label.Location = new Point(25, 50);
        label.Parent = form;
        label.ForeColor = Color.White;

        textBox.Parent = form;
        textBox.Location = new Point(25, 65);
        textBox.Width = 300;

        DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
        value = textBox.Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Value = " + value);
        return dialogResult;


    }

    private void Titlebar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    private  void ButtonCancel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private  void lblexit_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        form.Close();
    }
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you reduce it to the absolute necessary to show your issue?

Comment: The `static` form and buttons looks suspicious to me. I've never did something like this before in winforms.

Comment: `ReleaseCapture` is usually coupled with `SetCapture`. What is your intent with that call? Also, why use p/invoke when you can simply set `Form.Location`? And all these `static` fields are dangerous, while the `InputBox` is not `static`. And note that `form.ShowDialog` doesn't dispose the form after calling it, so next call to `InputBox` will add all these controls to the `static` form all over again. My suggestion is, move all these static field into the method (make them temp variables), remove all `DllImport`s and use `Form.Location` to set the appropriate location.

Comment: I don't really know why I use there `ReleaseCapture`, i just use it because i found a solution like this and it worked previously for me. I erased all the `static` but it still doesn't work. How would I do this with `Form.Location`?

Comment: `SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);`<-- where does `Handle` come from?

Comment: Does this problem only occur the second time you show a window?

Comment: Maybe the lblexit_click happens before/during the move? The form.Close() would dispose the form and its controls probably.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't know exactly, because this is just a code snippet I am trying to use. And it happens every time.

Comment: @Herman No, it doesn't happen before, I've checked that.

Comment: The buttonCancel and buttonOk variables are very buggy.  Their initialization works just once.  If the user closes the form then the controls those variables reference are disposed and trying to use them again throws this exception.  Initialize them in the method.  Same for the `form` variable btw.

Comment: @HansPassant Now I initiated them in the method, but it throws the same exception. And I updated the code above.